# Draw free 2d shapes dynamically in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, 2d

I want to be able to draw any 2d shape dynamically in 2d world. My games has moving elements, looking like circle when alone, that can fuse and make complex shapes when getting close together. The elements can still move and thus separate or modify the shape.

How can I draw that with Unity? I don't think the usual sprites can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do that with shaders (sounds complex to me, but utilises GPU).

Or...

Modify [sprite's vertices](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite-vertices.html) to introduce streching of the texture.